# How to display field values from ManyToMany through model

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following models with a `ManyToMany` `through` relationship.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="membership_invites",
    )
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

When displaying a `DetailView` for `Group` to print the `person.name` I can use:

```
 {% for person in group.person.all %}
 {{ person.name }}
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I add a reference to print `invite_reason` in this `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group has many memberships. And membership has one group and one person along with invite_reason. So, to get invite_reason for a specific person of a group you need to access it from the Membership model.

You can do the as the following:

```
  {% for membership in group.memebership_set.select_related('person') %}
           Person Name: {{ membership.person.name }}
           Invite Reason: {{ membership.invite_reason }} 
  {% endfor %}
```